# Uppy + Laravel can't upload file

Tags: laravel, uppy

Trying to use Uppy JS lib to upload file throug Laravel. Setted up simple upload form with there params:

```
const options = {
    endpoint: '/parts/image-upload',
    headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
};

uppyDashboard.use(XHRUpload, options);
```

And on the backend I'm getting

`Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The payload is invalid. in file /Users/rd/Projects/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php on line 195`

It's like Laravel trying to decrypt something what is already decrypted, anyway I'm in dead end.

Comment: I think this is not the solution, but a bug in your code. The header should be ```X-CSRF-TOKEN``` instead. You got typo.

Comment: Yes, X-XSRF-TOKEN is for cookies, missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can this code

```
 var uppy = new Uppy.Core({
                // debug: (...args) => console.debug(`[Uppy] [${getTimeStamp()}]`, ...args),
                // warn: (...args) => console.warn(`[Uppy] [${getTimeStamp()}]`, ...args),
                // error: (...args) => console.error(`[Uppy] [${getTimeStamp()}]`, ...args),
                autoProceed: true,
                restrictions: {
                    maxFileSize: 2000000,
                    maxNumberOfFiles: 10,
                    minNumberOfFiles: 1,
                    allowedFileTypes: ['image/*']
                }
            });
            uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
                target: ".UppyDragDrop",
                inline: true,
                showLinkToFileUploadResult: false,
                showProgressDetails: true,
                hideCancelButton: true,
                hidePauseResumeButton: true,
                hideUploadButton: true,
                proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
                locale: {}  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[id*=drag-drop-area]').each(function(){

var listing_id = $(this).attr('class');

var uppy = new Uppy.Core({
allowMultipleUploadBatches: true,
restrictions: {
maxFileSize: 100000000,
// maxNumberOfFiles: 8,
minNumberOfFiles: 1,
allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
}
})
.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
inline: true,
target: "#"+$(this).attr('id')+""
})
.use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
endpoint: 'upload',
formData: true,
bundle: true,
headers: {
'X-CSRF-Token': " {{ csrf_token() }} "
},
});

uppy.on('upload-success', (file, response) => {
response.body.data.forEach(function (item, index) {
console.log(listing_id);
var token = 
$('meta[name="csrftoken"]').attr('content');

$.ajax({
url: 'attach',
type: 'POST',
data: { '_token' : token, item, listing_id},
success: function(response) 
{
console.log('Updated');
},
error:function (e) {
console.log(e);
}
});
});
window.location.reload();
});
});
});
</script>
```

You create the endpoint which is the route name and attach at

> endpoint: ""

Then you return a response which you grab and do whatever on the last section.

```
uppy.on('upload-success', (file, response) => {
response.body.data.forEach(function (item, index) {
console.log(listing_id);
var token = 
 $('meta[name="csrftoken"]').attr('content');

$.ajax({
url: 'attach',
type: 'POST',
data: { '_token' : token, item, listing_id},
success: function(response) 
{
    console.log('Updated');
},
error:function (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
});
});
window.location.reload();
});
```

I hope this helps